# Scrolling Background Image

Tags: javascript, ipad, html, canvas

I'm trying to get a scrolling background image to work for a game I'm developing. The above code works fine for Safari on a Mac, however, it doesn't work on an iPad. My guess is that the backgroundY is resulting in a negative number which in turn throws me an error "INDEX_SIZE_ERR: DOM Exception 1"

```
backgroundY += 5;
if (backgroundY >= 3834) backgroundY = 0;
bg.drawImage(backgroundImg, 0, -backgroundY, 960, 4930);
```

Any ideas on how to easily scroll a background image that will work on the iPad? Ideally I'd like to instance the image and have it scroll through javascript as opposed to CSS. If I could possibly change the registration point of the image to the lower right corner, it wouldn't ever receive a negative image. Basically, the image is supposed to fly upwards on screen to emulate a sense of falling.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `getImageData`, along with `putImageData`

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTML/Canvas/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas

Now I dont recommend doing this for any other circumstance, but below is an example I put together using get/putImageData. The main thing is you can only get image data thats within the size of your canvas, and the same goes with putting back the imagedata. In the below example no negative values are used.

**[Live Example](http://www.somethinghitme.com/projects/bgscroll/)**

Comment: Would you have any suggestions on how to implement that? I've read through that document several times and am still having trouble implementing it.

Comment: @Hessam Ill try and whip up a demo of it today or tomorrow morning sometimes.

Comment: @Hessam Ok sorry for the delay here you go http://www.somethinghitme.com/projects/bgscroll/